Why onChange is called multiple times for single change?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker("Select movie", selection: $selectedItem, matching: .videos)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
            Task {
                await dummyFunc()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func dummyFunc() async{
        
    }
}

When I pick a video using photo picker, onChange is called four times instead of once. It only happens for async function. For non async function, it gets called only once. Is there any reason behind it ? What's the solutions ?

Try using .task(id: selectedItem) and get rid of that floating Task

I can't reproduce this, what iOS version is this for, what happens in dummyFunc?

It's .task in SwiftUI
